# How to resolve error "Undefined reference to `pcap_parse'"

Tags: pcap

I am trying to use the [libpcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) library in a C++ program.

I have downloaded `libpcap-1.0.0.tgz`, untared it, and then

```
./configer
make
make install
```

I have `libpcap.a` and `headers` with me, and I have written one sample program to test it. But it is giving me compiler errors as follows:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a(gencode.o): In function `.L151':
gencode.c:(.text+0x7f4): undefined reference to `pcap_parse'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am compiling this program using following command:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -lpcap
```

Am i doing anything wrong in building `libpcap` and `headers`?

Comment: What does the command `nm -a /usr/local/lib/libpcap.a | egrep parse` print?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to pass `-lpcap` before `test.cpp`

Comment: No, library names go *after* source file names in a command such as that.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing libstdc++-4.8-dev - this worked for me when I had a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Libpcap-devel using this command ( sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev ) if it doesn't work install flex too (sudo apt-get install bison)

good luck

Comment: No, he's downloading and building libpcap himself, rather than using a packaged version (and he didn't indicate that he was running a Debian derivative, so there's no guarantee that he even *has* apt-get!), so that's not the issue.

Comment: Flex and Bison are needed only if you're planning to compile libpcap, not if you're just going to use it and don't have a Flex scanner or Bison parser in your program.  He is compiling libpcap, but he succeeded in doing so, and therefore presumably already has lex or Flex, and yacc or byacc or Bison, installed.

Answer (score 0):

Include grammar.c which gets generated after you run ./configure and make.